# Unhandled Runtime Error ReferenceError: divRef is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

It says that my divRef is undefined. The code below is in index.js with import statements properly added and  applied in the return statement.

```
const divRef = useRef(null);

  // document.body.appendChild(script);
  useEffect(() => {
    const scriptContent = `
      if (typeof atOptions === 'undefined') {
        var atOptions = {
          'key' : 'KEY_VALUE',
          'format' : 'iframe',
          'height' : 250,
          'width' : 300,
          'params' : {}
        };
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = (location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'https' : 'http') + '://babinjectbother.com/KEY_VALUE/invoke.js';
        // if (divRef.current) {
          divRef.current.appendChild(script);
        // }
      }
    `;

    const scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
    scriptElement.innerHTML = scriptContent;

    // alert(divRef.current == undefined);
    // if (divRef.current) {
    divRef.current.appendChild(scriptElement); // <-- This causes the undefined error
    // }

    return () => {
      // if (divRef.current && divRef.current.contains(scriptElement)) {
        divRef.current.removeChild(scriptElement);
      // }
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: added code comment for clarification where the error is occuring.

Comment: you created a new script and the `const` isn't valid in that scope